# setting the lock to null

Tags: c#, null, locking

Is this legal? (i.e. setting the lock to null)

```
Class A
{
    public A() { }

    // Some stuff
}

Class B
{
    A a;

    public B()
    {
        A a = new A();
    }

    public void ResetA()
    {
        lock(a)
        {
            if(a != null)
            {
                a = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why shouldn't this be legal (except that it does not compile)?

Comment: You couldn't have come up with a worse example.  If "is this legal" means "will my code crash?" then the answer is no.  The C# compiler will generate a hidden variable to store the reference to the lock object so it cannot crash when it unlocks it.  If "is this legal" means "will my code malfunction?" then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *would be* legal if `a` wasn't a local variable in the constructor but a field.

Lock is initiated on a valid object. The reference is then nulled, but the lock still operates on the previous non-null value.

However if another lock attempt was made, it would end up being an error. See this question: [Why doesn't C# allow a null value to be locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226231/why-doesnt-c-sharp-allow-a-null-value-to-be-locked)

Answer (score 0):

The *direct experiment* you could have carried out shows that `lock(null)` throws *ArgumentNullValueException*. Another issue is that your code has a syntax error:

```
  public void ResetA() {
    lock(a) { ... // <- a is undefined; probably "B" class should have "A a" field
```

A typical way for using *lock* is

```
Class B {
  // Object to be used in locking.
  // It's private: we don't want to let anyone
  // interfere in our internal locking policy 
  // (so we do not use e.g. lock(this) etc)  
  private Object m_SyncObj = new Object();

  A a = new A();

  public void ResetA() {
    lock (m_SyncObj) {
      // A little bit strange lock block unless "a" is locked somewhere else as well
      a = null;
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: Hi I fixed the code and know how to solve the issue (like you suggested with m_SyncObj) but that wasn't my question