# Ensuring writes are seen from different reading threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-synchronization

Given the following class:

```
class C
{
   public int x = 0;

   public void F() {
       new Thread(G).Start();
       while (x == 0) { Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)); }
   }

   public void G() {
      Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
      Interlocked.Exchange(ref x, 1);
   }
}
```

I assume it is allowed under the `C#` standard for `new C().F()` to run forever yes, because there's nothing to force `F()` to retrieve the value of `x` from main memory each access. The `Interlocked.Exchange` here even doesn't help, as `F()` doesn't see the implementation of `G()` so may optimise away the access from main memory.

Is this analysis correct?

Furthermore, I understand making `x` volatile will resolve this, but is there anything else that would resolve this issue?

Comment: Don't use `volatile` in C#, unless you really, *really* know your way around it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384758/1086121. A normal `lock` statement is the way to go about this.

Comment: As canton7 mentioned, locking the object will force other threads to wait (thus syncrhonize) for the locking thread to release it thus making it atomic.

Comment: Writes *are* seen by other threads. Assuming there *are* other threads to see the writes - `new Thread(G).Start();` creates an orphaned thread object that's going to get garbage-collected

Comment: Even if that's solved, *reading* needs synchronization as well, either through a lock or `Interlocked.CompareExchange`

Comment: If `int` is not larger than native word size, then read/write is atomic : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9788/397807

Comment: C# spec also guarantees atomicity : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666/is-accessing-a-variable-in-c-sharp-an-atomic-operation#comment21288539_9788

Comment: You can use also `Thread.VolatileWrite` and `Thread.VolatileRead` (as a replacement of `volatile` keyword). `Interlocked.Exchange` isn't needed here at all as int32 assignment is atomic.

Comment: I think the fact that in his example the object assignment is on an `Int32` is just a coincidence (from the perspective of the OP). I think the question is more geared towards if the reference assignment isn't an object that is atomic.

Comment: I understand the writes are atomic for anything except custom structs, the issue is seeing the changes, not whether they’re atomic.

Comment: I think @DmytroMukalov 's `VolatileRead` and `VolatileWrite` is all that is required here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `lock` statement to force other threads to wait for it to become unlocked.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement