# sub-thread not returning to main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

this is my main thread:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(understand));      // create the thread for understand function
    oThread.Start();      // start the thread
    button1.Enabled = false;

    Thread.Sleep(1);      

    if (false == understand_status)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("i am in main thread");
    }
}
```

this is my sub-thread:

```
private void understand()
{
    int license_value=0;

    while (understand_status)
    {             
        ..............
        if (license_value < 29)
        {
            understand_status = false;
            ...........
        }
        if (false == understand_status)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("inside while");
            File.Delete("C:\\log.txt");
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("outside while");    
}
```

it is showing message "outside while" but not returning to main thread. where i am showing "i am in main thread". I am new to thread programming any help appreciated

Comment: are you using winforms or wpf

Comment: Either your thread takes more than a second to set `understand_status` to `false`, or else `understand_status` is the victim of jitter optimization (in which case marking it `volatile` should make the problem go away, but `volatile` is something you really should not be using at all; read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275/when-should-the-volatile-keyword-be-used-in-c)).

Comment: Actually, the thread.Sleep(1) would cause the thread to sleep for a millisecond, not a second..

Answer (score 0):

add oThread.Join() after thread is started

Comment: If you are going to start a thread and immediately `Join` it then why bother in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you use "volatile" keyword for declaration of understand_status variable like this:

```
 volatile bool understand_status = true;
```

Also try to use Join method insted of Thread.Sleep(1) like this:

```
 oThread.Join();
```

Comment: my main thread is UI thread if i will use join i won't able to acces UI.

Answer (score 0):

You start the thread which **asynchronously** starts some work. Your main thread continues it's work, but when checking `understand_status`, the other thread has not yet reached the point where you have changed the status, thus your `if` clause is not met and therefore nothing is shown.

Answer (score 0):

When you main thread gets to

```
if (false == understand_status)
{
     MessageBox.Show("i am in main thread");
}
```

'understand_status' is actually true since the other thread is still processing. This is a simple race condition.