# volatile properties can't be compiled in C# or do they?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compile following code :

```
internal volatile bool isRunning { get; set; }
```

But the compilation fails with error message like: "the volatile modifier
is not valid for that element". But the following code will be compiled fine:

```
internal volatile bool _isRunning;

internal bool isRunning{
    get { return _isRunning; }
    set { _isRunning = value; }
}
```

What is the difference between both code snippets??

Comment: A property is just a prettied up method call. What do you think a volatile method call should do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275/when-should-the-volatile-keyword-be-used-in-c

Answer (score 6):

[volatile (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx)

> The volatile keyword **can only be applied to fields** of a class or
>   struct. Local variables cannot be declared volatile.

I case of [Auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb384054.aspx) or a property, compiler creates a private backing field that can be accessed through get/set.  A field can be marked as `volatile`, but in case of of Auto implemented property, you don't explicitly define a field and thus can't mark it as volatile. That is why your first code (`internal volatile bool isRunning { get; set; }`)  snippet doesn't compile.

In case of second code snippet

```
internal volatile bool _isRunning;

internal bool isRunning{
    get { return _isRunning; }
    set { _isRunning = value; }
}
```

You are encapsulating `_isRunning` **field** through your property `isRunning`. The field `_isRunning` can be marked as `volatile`.

Comment: Yeah. So the difference is: The first version is not Csharp - at least not for any compiler.

Comment: @TomTom, that is true. This isn't allowed even in C# 6.0. and It shouldn't be. A property itself is nothing more than syntactic sugar for get/set methods. `volatile` can only be a field.

Answer (score 0):

A property with getters and setters actually compiles into methods in C#.

```
internal volatile bool isRunning { get; }
```

Would be like having

```
internal volatile bool getIsRunning()
{
    // Do something
}
```

The method isn't actually storing anything whereas the private member is.