# Thread seems to stop running when I call a given method in the same class, why?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class that constantly refreshes devices physically connected to PC via USB. The monitoring method runs on a thread checking a `_monitoring` flag, and `Start` and `Stop` methods just set and unset that flag.

My current problem is: when the thread is running, I get the expected "busy" and "not busy" console prints, but when I call `Stop` method, it keeps running `while(_busy)` forever, because somehow *the `_monitoringThread` seems to stop running!*

I suspect it stops running because the last print is always `busy`, that is, the `ExecuteMonitoring` runs midway and then nobody knows (at least I don't).

Pause debugging and looking at StackTrace didn't help either, because it keeps in the `while(_busy)` statement inside `Stop()` method, forever.

```
public class DeviceMonitor
{
    bool _running;
    bool _monitoring;
    bool _busy = false;
    MonitoringMode _monitoringMode;
    Thread _monitoringThread;

    readonly object _lockObj = new object();


    // CONSTRUTOR
    public DeviceMonitor()
    {
        _monitoringThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteMonitoring));
        _monitoringThread.IsBackground = true;
        _running = true;
        _monitoringThread.Start();            
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        _monitoring = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _monitoring = false;
        while (_busy)
        {                
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }


    void ExecuteMonitoring()
    {
        while (_running)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ExecuteMonitoring()");

            if (_monitoring)
            {
                lock (_lockObj)
                {
                    _busy = true;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("busy");

                if (_monitoringMode == MonitoringMode.SearchDevices)
                {
                    SearchDevices();
                }
                else
                if (_monitoringMode == MonitoringMode.MonitorDeviceConnection)
                {
                    MonitorDeviceConnection();
                }

                lock (_lockObj)
                {
                    _busy = false;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("not busy");              
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            _busy = false;                
        }
    }

    private void SearchDevices()
    {
        var connected = ListDevices();

        if (connected.Count > 0)
        {
            Device = connected.First();
            ToggleMonitoringMode();
        }
        else
            Device = null;
    }


    void MonitorDeviceConnection()
    {
        if (Device == null)
        {
            ToggleMonitoringMode();
        }
        else
        {
            bool responding = Device.isConnected;
            Console.WriteLine("responding " + responding);
            if (!responding)
            {
                Device = null;
                ToggleMonitoringMode();
            }
        }

    }


    void ToggleMonitoringMode()
    {
        if (_monitoringMode == MonitoringMode.SearchDevices)
            _monitoringMode = MonitoringMode.MonitorDeviceConnection;
        else
        if (_monitoringMode == MonitoringMode.MonitorDeviceConnection)
            _monitoringMode = MonitoringMode.SearchDevices;
    }

    enum MonitoringMode
    {
        SearchDevices,
        MonitorDeviceConnection
    }
}
```

Comment: `_busy` only appears 1 time in your code, and it's not even defined. Is that your REAL code?

Comment: Also, don't do that.  Instead, use `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: @Amit thanks for pointing, it is a typo from my part, it should be `_busy` everywhere, gonna correct it. Original code not in english.

Comment: Where is the Stop() method being called from ?

Comment: You need to replace the _busy with some Singaling event it's not just ManualResetEvent out there. Also you need a safe method of cancelling the running thread. Meanwhile I'm figuring out an optimal solution.

Comment: While I agree that the "busy wait" is bad, I disagree with advice to use `ManualResetEvent`. There are better, .NET-native thread synchronization mechanisms that should be used. That said, your main question seems to be why the `_busy` flag is never set to `true`; given your observation that the `_monitoringThread` actually winds up terminated, and that you never see the `"not busy"` message, it seems probable that the thread is throwing an exception before reaching the statement that clears the `_busy` flag.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it would be impossible to provide a good, useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is: optimization: The compiler sees that `_busy` is never changed inside the `Stop` method and it is therefore allowed to convert this to an endless loop by replacing `_busy` with `true`. This is valid, because the `_busy` field is not marked as being volatile and as such the optimizer doesn't have to assume changes happening on another thread.

So, try marking `_busy` as volatile. Or, even better - actually A LOT BETTER - use a `ManualResetEvent`:

```
ManualResetEvent _stopMonitoring = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ManualResetEvent _monitoringStopped = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ManualResetEvent _stopRunning = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void Stop()
{
    _stopMonitoring.Set();
    _monitoringStopped.Wait();
}

void ExecuteMonitoring()
{
    while (!_stopRunning.Wait(0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ExecuteMonitoring()");

        if(!_stopMonitoring.Wait(0))
        {
            _monitoringStopped.Unset();
            // ...
        }
        _monitoringStopped.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Code is from memory, might contain some typos.

Comment: Nice, nice, nice! :) . Two thoughts, though: 1) as you already said, it looks like ["volatile is evil"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17530556/401828); 2) I can already believe your alternative would be better, just haven't grasped yet why it would be __a lot__ better. Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: (by the way, declaring `volatile bool _busy` didn't solve the problem, gonna try the `ManualResetEvent` approach soon).

Comment: @heltonbiker: Yes, for one, because "volatile is evil". Mainly, because it is a highly complex keyword as you can see from the answer you linked. The simplistic explanation in my answer also highlights the fact, that it is just way too easy to get wrong. But the other reason is simply that a ManualResetEvent isn't performing an active wait like your loop with the `Thread.Sleep(5)` in it.

Comment: @heltonbiker: If the MRE doesn't solve the problem as well, we are missing some context here. The fact that only one answer exists shows that there is most likely no other reason *in the code you have shown*.