# Is locking required when only one thread accesses a value at a time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lock-free

My idea is to run a few operations asynchronously; I can guarantee that two operations will never run concurrently, but I can't guarantee that they will run on the same thread/CPU as the others.

```
// Example code
int myValue = 0;

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
    myValue++;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state2 => {
        Console.WriteLine(myValue);
    });
});
```

Is the output guaranteed to be `1` even without locking?

Maybe a call to `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` is required before the `Console.WriteLine(myValue)`?

Or maybe `myValue` should be made `volatile`?

I'm not really used to multithreading programming without locking, I hope someone can solve my doubts.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

What if I decide to use locking? Is this code guaranteed to output `1`?

If yes, why? Could not the compiler decide to store `myValue` on the register of a CPU?

I have never actually had any problem with a code like this, but I've only run my programs on x86 and x64 CPUs so far. What about MONO, ARM, and other "esoteric" platforms?

```
// Example code
object lockMe = new object();
int myValue = 0;

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
    lock(lockMe) {
        myValue++;
    }

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state2 => {
        lock(lockMe) {
            Console.WriteLine(myValue);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks again!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(myValue);` will always print `1`.  But be aware that its not guaranteed that `myValue` will already be incremented after you executed `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...);`

Comment: To "Or maybe `myValue` should be made `volatile`?" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17530556/2026276

Comment: @nozzleman May I ask how can the second operation (`Console.WriteLine`) be guaranteed to see the updated version of `myValue`? Could `myValue` not have been cached in a register of the CPU that executed the first operation (`myValue++`)? Forgive my uncertainty.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to avoid taking a lock? An uncontended lock is about a dozen nanoseconds. Almost no one can do low lock programming correctly, and almost no one needs to; why are you trying to do so?

Comment: I never actually wanted to do lock-free programming, I just wanted to explore the alternatives, but the more I read what people writes on the Internet the more I get convinced to abort this kind of creepy-programming and stick to the "old-fashioned" locks. :)

Then I have just one more doubt, I will update the original question now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, like *any other library functions which executes code in the other thread*, **garantees** that this **code will see every modification, visible by the current thread up to the function call**.

Because `myValue++` precedes `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` *in program order*, result of value's modification is seen by the caller thread. So `Console.WriteLine(myValue)` will definitely see updated value.

Locking, *volatile* modifier are completely unnecessary in that case.