# Debug / release mode — different behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2015, release, debug-mode

Two threads (main thread and another thread called T) have access to the same boolean field. T does nothing but `while (_bool) { }` and Main assigns false to `_bool` after 2 seconds.

On Debug, T exits the loop.

On Release, T never exits the loop.

Why?

#### EDIT:

Moreover, why `volatile` on `_bool` solves this?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private bool _bool = true;

        private static void Main()
        {
            var program = new Program();
            var t = new Thread(SomeThread);
            t.Start(program);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            program._bool = false;
            Console.WriteLine(program._bool);
        }

        private static void SomeThread(object obj)
        {
            var p = obj as Program;
            Console.WriteLine("Entered loop");
            while (p._bool)
            {

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Exited Loop");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use a lock while reading/writing `_bool`.

Comment: Your variable is not volitile

Comment: Mark your variable as volatile, else the release code can cache it's value for different threads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275/when-should-the-volatile-keyword-be-used-in-c

Comment: Edited the question regarding the Volatile.