# Howto avoid concurrently calling a method without blocking?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking, nonblocking

I want to run a cleanup task that might run for several seconds. Multiple threads could call this task but I want to run this task only once. All other invokations should just skip.

The following is my current implementation but I cannot imagine there is not a better solution in the .net framework resulting in less lines of code.

```
    object taskLock;
    bool isRunning;

    void Task()
    {
        if (isRunning) return;

        try
        {
            lock (taskLock)
            {
                if (isRunning) return;
                isRunning = true;
            }
            // Perform the magic
        }
        finally
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you could use a similar approach, but use a concurrent dictionary in place of the taskLock object. tbh -if it currently works, move on and break down the other items in your backlog

Comment: "I cannot imagine there is not a better solution" This is unorthodox problem, since by definition it is ridden with concurrency ambiguities. Depending on timing, the task might be run only once - or for every invoking thread. At the very least, it is inefficient.

Comment: Yes, it can be very inefficient but I do not see a better alternative to signal for a certain task to happen. An alternative could be to maybe use a reset event where the task just waits until another thread sets the event but I then have to manage an thread/task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a better solution. You can use [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583(v=vs.110).aspx), the code becomes simpler and lock-free:

```
class Worker
{
    private volatile int isRunning = 0;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        if (isRunning == 0 && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isRunning, 1, 0) == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                DoTheMagic();
            }
            finally
            {
                isRunning = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoTheMagic()
    {
        // do something interesting
    }
}
```

In this case `Interlocked.CompareExchange` does the following as an atomic operation (pseudo-code):

```
wasRunning = isRunning;
if isRunning = 0 then 
     isRunning = 1
end if
return wasRunning
```

From the MSDN documentation:

```
public static int CompareExchange(
    ref int location1,
    int value,
    int comparand
)
```

> If comparand and the value in location1 are equal, then value is
>   stored in location1. Otherwise, no operation is performed. The compare
>   and exchange operations are performed as an atomic operation. The
>   return value of CompareExchange is the original value in location1,
>   whether or not the exchange takes place

Comment: I like this solution but isn't the CompareExchange slower then the `if (isRunning) return;` ?

Maybe doing `if (isRunning == 1 || Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isRunning, 1, 0) == 1) return;` might be faster when the task would more often be running then not

Comment: @RamonSmits, yes it would be faster, but it should be `if (isRunning == 0 && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isRunning, 1, 0) == 0)` and you would need to declare `isRunning` as volatile. On the other hand `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is very fast. I don't believe you would get an appreciable gain.

Comment: @RamonSmits. I edited my answer to include the optimization. Here you have a micro-benchmark that compares the optimization https://gist.github.com/jesuslpm/77b60126c8d787c7a76b

Comment: Why is the 'volatile' keyword needed?

Comment: @RamonSmits because it can be modified by another thread. It prevents compiler from performing some optimizations that might lead to wrong results. It is related to memory fences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

Comment: @RamonSmits you may want to read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275/when-should-the-volatile-keyword-be-used-in-c