# c# terminating a thread hangs

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have looked at all the solutions for this topic but still cannot seem to accomplish the stopping of a thread without using Thread.Abort().
Here is the code: Main class code that creates the the thread:

```
            _pollingThread = new Thread(pollingThread);
            _pollingThread.Start();
```

And here is the thread:

```
 void _pollingThread()
 {
     while (continuePolling) //initially set to true
     {
          //do some things can take about 200ms to run
     }
 }
```

I next attempt to stop the thread from the main thread by setting continuePolling to false.

```
 private void form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     continuePolling = false;
     Thread.Sleep(1000);

     _pollingThread.Join(1000);

    if (_pollingThread.IsAlive) //always alive!
    {
        _pollingThread.Abort;
    }
 }
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Where and how is `continuePolling` defined? I don't think the code you've given is enough to replicate the problem you having.

Comment: Don't abort a thread, use a synchronization primitive to tell it to go away.

Comment: or use thread.interupt

Comment: thread.Join waits for the thread to finish. You will hang there. You need to tell your thread to stop by setting continuePolling to false

Comment: @pm100 only use exceptions when you don't expect them

Comment: Remove `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, it is not necessary because you are using `Thread.Join() `. The thread `_pollingThread ` will finish until the execution of method `_pollingThread` has been finished. So, it's important to check how often the loop  `while (continuePolling)` is evaluated. So, it's important that you post the full code of `_pollingThread`.

Comment: continuePolling is defined as volatile bool continuePolling = true;

Comment: You'd better not use `volatile` read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275/when-should-the-volatile-keyword-be-used-in-c

Comment: I cannot post the full code.  It's just too much.  However, it takes less than 100ms to run.

Comment: If you want to `Join` a thread with a timeout, you should check the result (bool) of the `Join` instead of checking the `IsAlive` property.

Comment: @J. van Langen I checked and it is false.  So the join never works.

Comment: If Join returns true, the thread is finished. The alive property might give a true, because internally the join is waiting on an event also and when it is triggered the thread is still closing. So the alive might give true as result. When the Join is ready, none of your code is executed anymore. The Alive isn't relevant in this purpose. It would be better to check the ThreadState.

Comment: My guess is that your thread is, at some point, invoking something synchronously on the GUI thread (or waits on the GUI thread through some other means). That effectively deadlocks the program, because the GUI thread is busy joining the thread.

Comment: Replace `Thread.Join(1000)` with just `Thread.Join()`, and then run the program. When you notice it's deadlocked, press the PAUSE button in visual studio, and examine what the background thread is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Abort/Interrupt to stop a thread, is bad programming. You never knew what it did and what it didn't. There is one exception for that *(like terminating hanging 3rd party code)*, even then consider it evil. You should use the [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) to tell the thread to terminate execution. The `ManualResetEvent` is thread-safe and works great.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyThread
{
    private ManualResetEvent _terminate = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private Thread _thread;

    private void PollingThread()
    {
        while(!_terminate.WaitOne(0))
        {
            // do your stuff, if you want a pause after each loop,
            // you should change the 0 of waitone. This way the 
            // termination isn't blocked when waiting
        }
    }

    public MyThread()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(PollingThread);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if(_thread != null)
        {
            _terminate.Set();
            _thread.Join();
            _thread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this.  It makes no difference.  The join never occurs.

Comment: I use the model for years and still works like a charm. Your thread probably hangs in a inner loop or waits on something else. You should debug it. Is there a forever running while in it? It should not..

Comment: Well that's interesting...I replaced everything in the thread with a Thread.Sleep(1000) and now it joins correctly.

Comment: This is very interesting.  I have one call to a method in a class that reads a serial port and that call always runs quickly.  When I issue a _terminate.Set() or continuePolling = false, this call never returns.  So in your example, PollingThread would have a call like data = BackEnd.Get_Data();  This always works fine but the minute there is a _terminate.Set() it never returns.  Why?  The serial port class is a static class.

Comment: I have changed direct access to the serial port class to an interface to another class that also access the serial port.  No more issues.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The serialport class probably blocks execution until it receives data.

Comment: I still recomment to replace the continuePolling with an event. It's way more solid. Another advantage is, that it can 'sleep' the but still can be terminated quickly (with a thread.sleep it cannot)

Answer (score 0):

continuePolling has to be declared `volatile`, otherwise there is no guarantee that modifications in one thread will be seen in any other thread.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile

Alternatively you might consider using something like `System.Timers.Timer` to run your polling action periodically.

Comment: the continuePolling is defined as volatile bool continuePolling = true;